# Get method in DetailView changes data transmition to templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to add a get method to my DetailView but it's not working. Once I add the get method, I loose the connection to the data on the template.

```py
    #I tried to change {{ object.field_name }} to
    #{{ post.field_name }}
    #{{ object_list.field_name }}


    # in app views I write :
    class PostDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post

    # in templates I write:
    <a>{{ object.author }}</a>

    # data is send to templates and it works fine
    # But then I want to add a get/post to the view:

    class PostDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = HomeForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    # Once I add the get method , data is not rendering on my template.
```

If someone could help me to figure out why data is not rendering in templates once I add the get method to my DetailView, it would be great. I've spent the afternoon/night searching but now my brain is fried...help, pls . tx tx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing your context data and in changed context data there is no object. you can remove the get method and add `get_context_data` so your correct code will be like this

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = HomeForm()
        context['form'] = form
        return context
```